# MATLAB how to plot contour with special LineWidth for certain value

Tags: matlab, line, contour, difference

I have the following script:

```
close all; clear all; clc;

x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);

y = linspace(0,4*pi);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);

values = -10:0.5:10;

figure

[C,hh] = contour(X, Y, Z, values,'r', 'LineWidth',1); 

clabel(C, hh, values, 'fontsize',7)
```

As you can see in the contour lines, all of the lines are plotted with LineWidth = 1. I would like to plot special line for the value = 0, with LineWidth = 2, how to set it? Thanks a lor for your help.

Comment: You'll have to make a secondary `contour` plot. See: [Highlight Specific Contour Levels](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/graphics-ex63999328-highlight-specific-contour-levels)

Comment: Thanks a lot excaza. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make a secondary contour plot to highlight the desired contour levels. The MathWorks has [an example of this](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/mw/graphics-ex63999328-highlight-specific-contour-levels) in the documentation.

For your case we'll have something like the following:

```
% Generate sample data
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);
values = -10:0.5:10;

% Generate initial contour plot
figure
[C,hh] = contour(X, Y, Z, values,'r', 'LineWidth',1); 
clabel(C, hh, values, 'fontsize',7)

% Generate second contour plot with desired contour level highlighted
hold on
contour(X, Y, Z, [0 0], 'b', 'LineWidth', 2); 
hold off
```

Which returns the following:

[image: yay]

Not that I've specified the single contour level as a vector. This is explained by [the documentation for `contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html):

> `contour(Z,v)` draws a contour plot of matrix `Z` with contour lines at the data values specified in the monotonically increasing vector `v`. To display a single contour line at a particular value, define `v` as a two-element vector with both elements equal to the desired contour level. For example, to draw contour lines at level `k`, use `contour(Z,[k k]`)

If you want to highlight multiple levels then this does not apply (e.g. `contour(X, Y, Z, [-1 0], 'b', 'LineWidth', 2)` to highlight `-1` and `0`)